# IBM MobileFirst Platform - How to Call resource WS (JAX-RS) in navigator?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to make a simple example of a connection to a WS (JAX-RS), when I call from the browser, I should return a string but I get the following error message:

> missing_authorization, this is the URL to access the resource (REST):
>   http://localhost:10080/PruebaWSProject/adapters/MyAdapter/users/pramirez

When I test it directly from MobileFirst Studio using "Call MobileFirst Adapter",  it works perfectly.

It seems to be a problem with HTTP authentication, apparently I have to set something in the XML file server: authenticationConfig.xml, but I do not know what I have to put and I read the following in a web:

Disabling the authentication requirement for a specific procedure.
You can do so by adding the securityTest="wl_unprotected" property to the  element in the adapter XML file.

I do not know how to turn off the security to call the resource to obtain the chain. The name of the classes generated by the Java adapter are: MyAdapterResource and MyAdapterApplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Adapters are protected by default.

When you use "Call MobileFirst Adapter", a test token is automatically added to help you preview.

If you want to test your adapter outside of the wizard, you have 2 main options:

1. Disable security by adding `@OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)` before your procedure code (in `MyAdapterResource`). Keep in mind that your procedure will no longer be protected. See [Protecting Adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/oauth-based-security-model/#protectAdapt).
2. Generate a test token manually. You can request a test token which you will add to your HTTP headers. See [In Postman](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/#testing)

The instructions you saw regarding `securityTest="wl_unprotected"` are for JavaScript adapters, not Java.